# Word Problems: Turning Sentences into Numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I go about solving the following problem? "A fourth of the product of a number and 8 is 3 times, and four less than, the number."

Comment: Let $x$ be the number. Then, does "3 times, and four less than, the number" mean $3x-4$?

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{8n}{4} = 3n-4$. solve from there.

This gives us 8n = 12n - 16

-4n = -16

n = 4.

Check it back into the original equation

Comment: Thanks. Where'd you get the 16 though?

Comment: $(4) \frac{8n}{4} = (3n-4)(4)$.

This is equal to 8n = 3n(4) + (-4)(4) = 12n - 16

Answer (score 0):

Imagine putting brackets around phrases in the sentence, according to its grammatical structure:

[a fourth of [the product of [a number] and 8]] is [four less than [3 times [the number]]

(I had to cheat a little to make this work by rearranging word order.)  Now, let $x$ be the number.  Working from the innermost expression outwards, we can replace each bracketed expression with mathematical notation.

**Before "is":**

- [a number] --> $x$
- [the product of $x$ and 8] --> $x \cdot 8$
- [a fourth of $(x \cdot 8)$] --> $\frac{1}{4} \cdot (x \cdot 8)$

**After "is":**

- [the number] --> $x$
- [3 times x] --> $3 \cdot x$
- [four less than $(3 \cdot x)$] --> $(3 \cdot x) - 4$

The "is" here means that the two expressions are equal.  That gives us:

$$\frac{1}{4} \cdot (x \cdot 8) = (3 \cdot x) - 4$$

You can solve the problem from here using algebra.