# Yet Another Word Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I always get stuck and I hate this. Along with the help of solving the following problem, can you give suggestions as to how to not get stuck on how to start solving? "Twice the sum of a number and 60 is 6 times the product of 7 and the number."

Comment: The tricky thing is the implicit parentheses. Twice (the sum of a number and $60$) is $6$ times (the product of $7$ and the number). Now it writes itself: $(2)(x+60)=6(7x)$.

Comment: You might want to wait for an answer to [your first question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701139/word-problems-turning-sentences-into-numbers) before asking again... this is very similar.

Comment: Every answer in this post has received a downvote. I'm compelled to ask why?

Comment: Beats me, I never downvote. I picked a best answer, that's about it other than thanking users. Who downvoted this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x$ be the number. Then, the equation is
$$2(x+60)=2x+120=6\cdot(7x)=42x$$
So, subtract $2x$ from both sides, and solve for $x$ by division!

Comment: Thanks! When you say 2 from both sides -- it's 2 - 2 and 2 minus 42x right?

Comment: You've got $42x=2x+120$. So, subtract $2x$ from both sides to get $42x-2x=40x=2x+120-2x=120$. Divide both sides by $40$ to get $x=3$.

Answer (score 2):

Let the number be $x$. Twice the sum of $x$ and $60$. Twice (the sum of $x$ and $60$). Twice $(x + 60)$. $2 (x + 60)$

"Is" essentially means "is equal to". $6$ times the product of $7$ and the number.  $6$ times $7$ and $x$. $6$ times $7x$. $6 \times 7 \times x = 42x$

We end up with the equation: $$ 2(x + 60) = 42 x \implies 120 = 40x \implies x = 3 $$

Always start by denoting the number given. Then go word by word. Interpret key words like "times", "is", "twice", "thrice" properly. And separate the phrases with commas when needed.

Comment: Yup! Thats what  the OP wanted. To comprehend the word problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take wherever 'is' shows up and slap in equals sign in there. 'A number' means use a variable, so let's call it $n$. Twice means $(2\cdot)$ and product also means $(\cdot)$. So we have
$$
2\cdot (n+60)=7\cdot n.
$$
We know to use parentheses around $(n+60)$ since it's twice the sum, not twice the number.

Comment: You would need to multiple by 6 as well 6(7*n)?

Comment: $6$ times the product of $7$ and the number??